# Print some code from a foreach loop at each predetermined number

Tags: php

My code is looping through some content and outputting some code.

I need to work out a way of telling my code to output some predefined text every X loops. For example:

> Task: print "code here" on loop item 1
>   and every 4 further loops.

So "code here" will only be outputted on foreach loop item 1, 4, 8, 12

Comment: The devil is in the details here. When you say "Loop item 1,4,8,12", are you referring to them with reference to Arrays (wherein the first line in an array is actually indexed as "0")? Or do you mean on the first loop? Also, you say "...every 4 further loops", technically, that would mean that it would happen for loop item 1, and then 4 further loops would be item 5, then item 9, ... Can you clarify this, possibly with a basic example?

Comment: PHP arrays start at index 0, so if you meant "the first element and every 4th element thereafter", you should have written "0,4,8,12".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$count = 0;
foreach( $yourArray as $oneElement ){
  $count++;
  if( $count==1 || $count%4==0 )
    echo 'code here';
}
```

Comment: This works well. Out of interest, could I extend this to use two different bits of logic:

print "code X" on item 1, 5, 9, 13 (1 and every 5)

and

print "code Y" on item 4, 8, 12, 16 (every 4)

You can probably tell, I am creating grid code.

Comment: Well, to have it execute on 1 and every multiple of 4, the code above should work. If you want it to be 1 and every multiple of 5 (1,5,10,15...), then simply replace `$count%4` on Line 4 of my Answer with `$count%5`. If you want it on 1 and every multiple of 6, then `$count%6`, and so on.

Comment: This was helpful. Can someone point me to some more information about how the % conditional works? Thanks!

Comment: % is the "modulus" operator in PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).
In the example `A%B` it will return the remainder of `A` when divided by `B`.
So `6%4` will return `2`, `100%1000` will return `100`.
It means you can find out whether one number if divisible by another, so to test whether `Y` is divisible by `3`, you can test it with `Y%3==0` (as, if it is divisible, the remainder will be 0).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using an array with numeric sequential keys, the extra counting variable is not necessary:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  if ($key == 1 || ($key > 1 && $key % 4 == 0))
    echo 'special string on 1,4,8,12...'; 
  // your code here
}
```

Note that when you check for every 4th iteration via `% 4` you have to make sure you're not printing on the 0'th element, hence the `$key > 1 &&...`

Comment: If you were to assume that the array has numeric and sequential keys, would it not also be safe to assume that the keys would all be positive, and therefore remove the `$key > 1 &&` part of your solution?

Comment: @Lucanos Array indexes start at 0, and with out the check for `$key > 1` this would print the extra string on 0,1,4,8,12, not 1,4,8,12. Several other solutions suffer from this flaw.

Comment: @Lucanos: We need `$key > 1`, so we don't print on the zeroth element.

Comment: @meagar: Understood, but then we are also presuming that the OP is referring to "Item 1" as being the second element in a zero-indexed array, rather than the more widely used definition wherein "Item 1" is the first item.

Comment: @Lucanos I would agree, except he specifically wrote out "item 1, 4, 8, 12". If you're going to assume he meant "1st item", then you have to also assume he meant "4th item, 8th item..." and the indexes you want are 0,3,7,11... Either way, `if( $count==1 || $count%4==0 )` is wrong.

Comment: @meagar: From the looks of things, and the OP's responses, I did read the spec correctly, so I would have to persist that `if( $count==1 || $count%4==0 )` is, in fact, correct.

Comment: @Lucanos Hey, I can't help it if you interpreted an incorrect spec incorrectly and somehow the two wrongs canceled each other out :p

Comment: @meagar: I am more than happy to be corrected here, but I think you are making assumptions on my part. I do not believe I interpreted the spec incorrectly - I read it with the view that the person asking the question was probably doing so in basic terms (rather than terms which you might use - whereas you would consider the first element in an array "Item 0", I realised that he probably meant the same thing when he said "Item 1"). I just don't see your point, is all.

Answer (score 0):

Just write out the logic. It is pretty easy:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++)
{
    if ($i == 1 || $i % 4 == 0)
        echo "Print code";
}
```

Comment: @meager I write it so often that I forgot I was going to start this one at 1 not 0.

Comment: Now it skips the first element entirely :p

Comment: @meagar My loop just starts at 1 vs 0. There is no element skipped.

Comment: I'm making the assumption that this code will be added to an existing loop which does something other than simply output the code.